# Gmail SMTP authentication always fail

Tags: python, authentication, go, smtp, gmail

I created this software in python 3

```
import smtplib
TO = 'anywhere@mail.com'
SUBJECT = 'Text subject of the mail'
TEXT = 'Text of the mail'

gmail_sender = 'yourMail@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = 'password'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)
BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                    'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                    '', TEXT])
try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
    print ('email sent')
except:
    print ('error sending mail')
server.quit()
```

The first day the software worked well but now I always have an authentification error from gmail :

```
   smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o81-v6sm9180362wmo.38 - gsmtp')
```

What I did already is :

I desactivated the unlock captchar from this link :

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

and I have enabled the less secure apps from this link:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

But still the same, I can't send an e-mail anymore. It doesn't seems that there's a Python software problem because I wrote the same software in Go and I still receive the same error.

Answer (score -1):

It’s solved. My login was wrong.